# Fast count number of colours on image

Tags: php, jquery, image

I need to determine number of colours for an image. The problem is that if image was saved inappropriate with compression it has some colour variations so 2 colour image become around 100 if calculate directly. Also direct count by determining colour for each pixel is rather slow. So I will appreciate any lead or algorithm of how to fast accomplish the task. As an example of how it should work - teespring.com on design creation get correct results while uploading "noisy" image and it get results very fast.

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this task?

Comment: @scragar - it can be a jQuery extension or plugin that can do that.

Comment: @Hemantwagh07 - Direct colour calculation, approximations... but results are not consistent from image to image. I think it should be some comparison table between printing colours (pantone for example) and rgb.